Incomplete experiments, note to reviewer?
I'm submitting to NeurIPS today and some of my experiments are not complete.
I think my paper is a fair submission even without those results, but the results I'm currently waiting on would clear up the last of my own criticism of the work.
Obviously, the reviewers should only review the work based on the results I present. But, perhaps they will be less confident in a negative review if there is scope for these results. I want to write a note to the reviewers mentioning my partial results and asking them to consider waiting for our rebuttal if they see the lack of this experiment as a weakness.
I see there are discussions on doing this for linked content and resubmissions, but is it normal to do so here (and if so where shall I put it)?
In case it helps, the full story is that I lost access to the server I was using to train these experiments, haven't been able to regain yet, and am trying to hack the code to run on very limited VRAM. But with just four hours to the deadline it doesn't look like I'll be able to fill more than one or two cells in my big table.
With NeurIPS getting over 21000 abstract submissions this year, I expect the reviewer load + competition will be sufficiently high that any scope for criticism might be exploited by reviewers to quickly dismiss my work. (Maybe it will also mean that they won't care about the absence of this experiment-- I welcome your comments).

Just submit what you have. The story is unfortunate but they receive way too many submissions for anyone to care.

@user176372 yeah, that's what I ended up doing. But I regret it. I think putting something Appendix would have been appropriate. (Or as part of a justification in checklist that we have to submit along with the paper-- I feel that might be one of the first places reviewers look).

Just imagine being a reviewer, though. You've got 20, 30, 50 or whatever of these things to sift through. One of them has a table in it that is literally incomplete. I'd personally be so harried that I'd just recommend a reject immediately without parsing the rest, assuming that the whole thing was incomplete.

Hmm, I don't mean putting an incomplete table. I mean, kinda reducing the scope of the experiment to a "preliminary" one that fits the results, within or accompanied by a note.

Also, I would hope the first round of reviewers are not expected to sift through double digits of these. At least when the # of abstract submissions was 12000 @ 3-4 reviews per paper (just 2 years prior!), they were able to find 10000 reviewers
